# Fitting a linear model with non gaussian noise

Tags: regression, extreme-value

I am trying to evaluate the elasticity of prices of some goods. I am concerned about the gaussianity of the noise in the prices. With non gaussianity I am referring to the non existence of the firt/second moment fo the distribution of the error. Is there a way to fit linear model without the assumption of gaussianity of the error?

Comment: A linear model does not assume a guassian distribution for the errors. The assumption is necessary when you want to estimate confidence or prediction intervals. Without the normal assumption, you can calculate these via bootstrap methods.

Comment: Although "non-gaussianity" does not mean "non-existence of moments", but rather non-symmetry and/or skewness/excess kurtosis, you specifically mention the possibility of non-existence of first and second moments. Does this come from theoretical considerations which tell you that the real-world situation under study would be well represented by such a distribution, for example a Cauchy distribution? Or somehow the data itself made you think of that possibility?

Comment: You can do a variety of robust fits which don't require even the mean to exist. That's a pretty big area. Is this simple regression (one $x$) or multiple regression?

Comment: I explained in wich term I have used the termn non gaussian. I know that can be intended in differente manner. Which other term I have could used in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and it is used quite a bit nowadays. A possible alternative to the Gaussian distribution consists of using skew distributions. For example, skew versions of the Student t distributions.

Let $f$ and $F$ be the Student $t$ density and distribution functions with $\nu>0$ degrees of freedom, respectively. Then, you can use the following asymmetric distributions for the errors:

1. [Two-piece Student t density.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375804000254)

$$s_1(x;\mu,\sigma,\gamma,\nu) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma}\left[f\left(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma(1+\gamma)};\nu\right)I(x<\mu) + f\left(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma(1-\gamma)};\nu\right)I(x\geq\mu) \right],$$

$\gamma\in(-1,1)$.

1. [Skew-symmetric Student t density.](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A14n416.pdf)

$$s_2(x;\mu,\sigma,\gamma,\nu) = \dfrac{2}{\sigma}f\left(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma};\nu\right)F\left(\lambda\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma};\nu\right),$$

$\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$.

These distributional assumptions can be used to produce a regression model which is more robust to departures from symmetry of the errors and the presence of outliers.

So, in the context of linear regression, you have the model

$$ y_j = x_j^{\top}\beta + \epsilon_j,$$

where $\epsilon_j\stackrel{ind.}{\sim} s_1\,\text{or}\,s_2$. So, your likelihood, for a sample with $n$ observations, becomes

$$L(\beta,\mu,\sigma,\gamma,\nu)=\prod_{j=1}^n s_i(y_j;x_j^{\top}\beta,\sigma,\gamma,\nu),\,\,\,i=1\,\,\,or\,\,\,2,$$

which can be maximised using your favourite optimisation method.

Comment: I thought all the properties of the estimates obtained from a linear regression are satisfied regardless of the distribution of noise - and only p-values / confidence intervals / significance tests are affected. So what is the statistical reason why we should run anything other than linear regression in this case, if all we care about is robustness of estimates?